# Solr enable grouping by default

Tags: solr, grouping

I use **Solr 3.3** and I would like to group results.

I use **Solritas Search UI** for displaying the results. When I search for a word '**test**' I get the result documents .

The URL looks like this .

> http://localhost:8983/solr/browse?q=test

Wat I want is I would like to group my results based on some field. I achieve this by changing the browser URL manually.

> http://localhost:8983/solr/browse?q=test&group=true&group.field=name

Is there a way by which we can change the default search component to Grouping and specify  what field the result needs to be grouped .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your solrconfig.xml, search for the "browse" handler (typically under `<requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">`) and add those parameters to the "defaults" list:

```
<str name="group">on</str>
<str name="group.field">name</str>
```